# Linear Independence and Component Vectors

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Let $V = ℝ^2$ and $v=(1,2)$, $w=(1, -1)$. Show that $\{v,w\}$ are linearly independent. Find the components of $av+bw$.

I know how to find linear independence (set $av+bw=0$ and solve for $a, b$ finding that $a=b=0$. However, I'm a bit confused about the wording of finding the components of $av+bw$. Don't we already know that the components are $(0,0)$ since they're linearly independent? Help here would be nice, just to get me in the right direction. Thanks.

Comment: Please, try to make the titles of your questions more informative. E.g., *Why does $a<b$ imply $a+c<b+c$?* is much more useful for other users than *A question about inequality.*
From [How can I ask a good question?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/589/): *Make your title as descriptive as possible. In many cases one can actually phrase the title as the question, at least in such a way so as to be comprehensible to an expert reader.* You can find more tips for choosing a good title [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/10144/).

Answer (score 2):

I skip the proof of linear independence, as you said you already know how to do that. Now, note that
\begin{aligned}av+bw&=a(1,2)+b(1,-1)\\&=(a,2a)+(b,-b)\\&=(a+b,2a-b)\end{aligned}
So the components of $av+bw$ are $a+b$ and $2a-b$. That's it.

Answer (score 1):

If they're not independent, then there exist $x,y\in \mathbb{R}-\{0\}$ such that

$$x(1,2)+y(1,-1)=(0,0)$$

It means that $x+y=0$ and $2x-y=0$, but see that this means that 
$$(2x-y)+(x+y)=3x=0$$

So it means that $x=0$, that imply that $y=0$, so they must be linearly independent.